# How to resolve BackgroundContainer.dll error on startup?

Tags: dll, boot, malware

When I start my desktop it gives me an error about BackgroundContainer.dll

> There was a problem starting c:\Users\Ventsislav\AppData\Local\Conduit\BackgroundContainer\BackgroundContainer.dll
>
> The specified module could not be found.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Also this can be easily removed using hijackthis.. http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2014/03/how-to-remove-backgroundcontainerdll.html

Answer (score 30):

I didn't find any entries relating to this in the registry, but I did find it in Task Scheduler.

- Open Control Panel
- Open Administrative Tools
- Open Task Scheduler
- Click on `Task Scheduler Library`
- Scroll through the list until you find `BackgroundContainer`
- Right click on the entry
- Click on `Delete` on the menu that pops up.
- Close all windows, reboot computer

The result is no more error on start up.

Answer (score 5):

This was a malware. It was removed by your AntiVirus Scanner, but the registry entries are still present to start the malware at startup.

Start `regedit.exe` and search (<kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL+F</kbd>) for `BackgroundContainer.dll` and delete all entries you find.

Comment: I actually had two popups. Doing Buffy's answer and then this answer got rid of both of them!

Answer (score 3):

1. Press <kbd>Windows Key + R</kbd>
2. In run dialog, type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Go to `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
4. Delete `BackgroundContainer.dll`
5. Reboot PC